# Change PieChart stroke color

Tags: colors, flutter, pie-chart

The default color of PieChart stroke is white, how can I change it to be transparent?

See example code https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/donut.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok figured that stroke color is set by constructor, so here is a hack solution.
Create a new class that extends ArcRendererConfig, and create a new constructor with your desired values like this:

```
class MyConfig extends ArcRendererConfig {
  var stroke;

  MyConfig() : this.stroke = StyleFactory.style.black;
}
```

Comment: I also opened issue with google https://github.com/google/charts/issues/180